# How to use INSIGNIA USB bluetooth adapter on Debian (Kali Linux)?

Tags: debian, hardware, kali-linux, bluetooth

I've just purchased a USB Bluetooth adapter for my computer.

The brand is Insignia and I was wondering if it's possible to use it on Debian (Kali Linux)?

Ok I got it to recognise the USB device by doing:

modprobe btusb

echo "19ff 0239" >> /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id

But it can't find any devices?

Answer (score 1):

full instructions to get it bluetooth usb to work on ubuntu 14.04

// all done in sudo
    sudo -s

// find device id

```
lsusb
```

// Bus 003 Device 003: ID 19ff:0239 Dynex

// copy id

```
modprobe btusb
echo "19ff 0239" >> /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id
```

// start bluetooth

```
hcitool dev
hcitool scan
hcitool dev

hciconfig hci0 reset
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

Open app 
    System > prefs > bluetooth